# PineScript: Why when input defval replaced with the same constant value changes calculation results?

Tags: pine-script

Cleaning up my strategy code and decided to remove some inputs and replace them with the default value as constant.
If I plot both the original and replacement values, they are the same, as expected.
However, the calculation results of the script changes.

Example:

//Initial code

risk_input = input(1, minval=0.1, title="Risk %")

//New code

risk_input = 1

The new code returns a different calculation result, (even if I explicitly define the variable type)

Does anyone have an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by declaring the constant with a decimal point:

//New code Corrected

risk_input = 1.0

I still don't know why this worked. If anyone has any comments, please share.